# fetch current date record of dd/mm/yyyy format in php mysql

Tags: php

I am stuck with an query. Actually i want to fetch current date records from my database and the below code probably fetches all my current date records. But it fetches in d/m/y (26/01/14) format but i need in dd/mm/yyyy (26/01/2014) .
Below is the code which gives output as d/m/y format:

```
<?php
ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$today = date('d-m-y');
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE DATE(startdate) = '$today'");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>Startdate</th>
<th>Details</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['startdate'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['details'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried with the above code and also tried to change the date format i.e :

```
$today = date('d-m-y');
```

to `$today = date('dd-mm-yyyy');`

I am not understanding what i am missing. Just need some help in this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

```
$today = date('d/m/Y');
```

Also if you need to convert another date to your date format:

```
$my_date = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP date formats: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You should use: `$today = date("d-m-Y");`

Capital Y is the full year - 2014

Comment: I made this change on my code the same as you posted but this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL query you can use

```
Select  DATE_FORMAT(startdate,"%d/%m/%Y") from persons where DATE(startdate) = '$today'");
```

OR in PHP you can use

```
$my_date = $row['startdate'];
$date = DATE("d/m/Y",strtotime($my_date));
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just format the date using mysql date_format() function?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Are you providing an answer or asking a question? Answers don't usually contain question marks.